# How to set iPad Pro static launch image

Tags: ios, image, ipad, launch

Looking at the Apple Human Interaction Guidelines in the section on Graphics->Launch Screen it says the following about Static Launch Screen Images [Apple HIG](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/)

"It’s best to use an Xcode storyboard for your launch screen, but you can provide a set of static images if necessary. Create static images in different sizes for different devices, and be sure to include the status bar region."

It then lists all the devices supported in iOS 10.

Does anyone know how this is done, for example for the 12" iPad Pro? There is nowhere to add an image for this in the asset catalog.  Do I have to use an UILaunchImages array in the Info.plist file? If so does anyone have an example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to use UILaunchImages in the Info.plist

Here is Apple's documentation on it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW28

And here is what an example looks like:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Img320x568ptsPort@2x</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Img320x568ptsLdsc@2x</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Img320x480ptsPort@2x</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Img320x480ptsLdsc@2x</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Img375x667ptsPort@2x</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Img375x667ptsLdsc@2x</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Img414x736ptsLdsc@3x</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Img414x736ptsPort@3x</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Cheers I'll check this out. Do you know if this a replacement for using an asset catalog, or can I use this to just add the missing iPad pro ones from the message catalog. For example do I have to add all the launch image options here, or can I just have the iPad pro ones an the app will pick up the other ones form the specified asset catalog.

Comment: Finally got this working by 1. Turning off the use of asset catalogs for launch images. 2. Moving the referenced launch images to the Xamarin project level so that they are in the root bundle. I may be able to make this cleaner by looking at the <BundleResources> options in the Xamarin project - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_resources/